# Issue with Expense Tracker Chart in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, chart.js

**Description:**

I'm working on an expense tracker using the MERN stack, and I'm encountering issues with the chart on the main home page. The problems include:

1. **Multiple Inputs:** The chart is not handling multiple inputs for both income and expenses correctly.
2. **Date Alignment:** The dates and the corresponding income and expense data are not aligning as expected.
3. **Sorting:** I want the chart to display data in ascending order according to the date.
4. **Handling Multiple Inputs:** I want both expenses and incomes to be able to take multiple inputs.

Here's the relevant code snippet for the chart:

```jsx
import React from 'react'
import {Chart as ChartJs, 
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend,
    ArcElement,
} from 'chart.js'

import {Line} from 'react-chartjs-2'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { useGlobalContext } from '../../context/globalContext'
import { dateFormat } from '../../utils/dateFormat'

ChartJs.register(
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend,
    ArcElement,
)

function Chart() {
    const {incomes, expenses} = useGlobalContext()

    const combinedData = incomes.map((income, index) => {
        const incomeAmount = income.amount
        const expenseAmount = expenses[index]?.amount || 0
        return incomeAmount - expenseAmount
    })

    const data = {
        labels: incomes.map((inc) => dateFormat(inc.date)),
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Net Income',
                data: combinedData,
                backgroundColor: 'green',
                tension: .2
            }
        ]
    }


    return (
        <ChartStyled >
            <Line data={data} />
        </ChartStyled>
    )
}

const ChartStyled = styled.div`
    background: #FCF6F9;
    border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 100%;
`;

export default Chart
```

I appreciate any help or guidance on resolving these issues. Thank you!